# how to return string for model class which its own field has choices in Django

Tags: django

I have a simple model class as follow:

```
class Lang(models.Model):
    various_languages=(
        ('english','english'),
        ('french','french'),
        )

    language = models.CharField(max_length=48, choices= various_languages)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.language
```

I added the model to the admin as follow:

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.

from .models import Lang

class LangAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Lang, LangAdmin)
```

I expect to have the language as string in the table on the admin page since I used the function:

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.language
```

but what I get is (Lang object) demonstrated on the table. How can I solve this. any suggestion or help is appreciated.

Note: I use Django 1.11.4 version, Python3.6.5, mysql 5.7.22

Comment: it seems to be correct, did you re run the server, and reload the page to see the effect?

Comment: yes, I did. and still have the same thing

Comment: register the Model without ModelAdmin

Comment: I tried it and still the same. also I comment choices and let it a normal field without choices and ironically the choices still appear in the admin page.

Comment: even this action required a `makemigrations` `migrate`

Comment: I did makemigrations and migrate. also I went to mysql database , I dropped the whole database and create it again. then I went to migration file and delete all file. then I makemigrations and migrate and create a superuser. and still have the same thing

Comment: make sure that you are running the server on the correct path on the command line, and not on a similar copy.